# I need to enter same value of attribute (id) as the previous table in another table

Tags: html, jsp

I have two tables, one in where I insert details of people who will be registering and another one table where I insert details of their routes. I need a shared id for each person details and routes. 
How can I do this? I have never done anything similar, so please bear with me.

This is the code for first table, in where id is inserted:

```
Integer maxid=0;
Integer id;
String Id=request.getParameter("id");
String title=request.getParameter("title"); 
session.putValue("userid",title); 
String fname=request.getParameter("fname"); 
String lname=request.getParameter("lname"); 
String email=request.getParameter("email"); 
String password=request.getParameter("password"); 
String cb=request.getParameter("cb");
String type=request.getParameter("type");
String name=request.getParameter("name");

String regid=request.getParameter("regid");
String lno=request.getParameter("lno");
String mnum=request.getParameter("mnum");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","ankurmisra"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs;
ResultSet rs2;
String str=" " ;
 rs2=st.executeQuery("Select max(id) as maxid from enter");
      while(rs2.next())
                  {
          maxid=rs2.getInt("maxid");
      }
      id = maxid + 1;
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into enter values ('"+id+"','"+title+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+password+"','"+mnum+"','"+cb+"','"+type+"','"+name+"','"+regid+"','"+lno+"')");
```

This is the code for second table where I need same id to be inserted:

```
String id=request.getParameter("id");
String pickup=request.getParameter("pickup"); 
String leave1=request.getParameter("leave1"); 
String going=request.getParameter("going"); 
String coming=request.getParameter("coming"); 
String message=request.getParameter("message");
String detour=request.getParameter("detour");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","ankurmisra"); 
Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs; 
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into check values ('"+id+"',"+pickup+"','"+leave1+"','"+going+"','"+coming+"','"+message+"','"+detour+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If those two insertion have to happen at the same time,
you can try to use <jsp:forward> action tag.

<jsp:forward> shares its request object to the targeted page.

For example,
1. insert details.
2. At the last of the detail insertion code,
place code below

```
<jsp:forward page="route.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

3. Then route.jsp can share the 'id' value of detail.jsp.

---

If they don't happen at the same time,
try to use jsp session or cookie to store and retreive the 'id' value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ..I will try the above method !! :)